# ERROR: Package 'web3' requires a different Python: 2.7.15 not in '>=3.5.3,<4'

Tags: python, ethereum

I am using the following [link](https://medium.com/haloblock/how-to-use-oyente-a-smart-contract-security-analyzer-solidity-tutorial-86671be93c4b) to install Oyente tool

I have got Python 3.6.9 installed on my Ubuntu 18.04/. When I am running the command pip2, I am getting error messages:

```
    zulfi@lc2530hz:~$ python3 --version
Python 3.6.9
zulfi@lc2530hz:~$ source envsp/bin/activate
(envsp) zulfi@lc2530hz:~$ pip2 install oyente
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
Collecting oyente
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/13/3c/52b8dee604cbdf35c1d65a141b779d9c14c8d313251c697b40a93f58d3d5/oyente-0.2.7-py2-none-any.whl
Collecting web3
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/85/01/eacb73ae16364295bf26cba4aacc94e513f5feae54dbb5f8121bec697e49/web3-4.8.1.tar.gz
ERROR: Package 'web3' requires a different Python: 2.7.15 not in '>=3.5.3,<4'
(envsp) zulfi@lc2530hz:~$
```

Somebody please guide me how to solve this error.

Zulfi.

Comment: That appears to be specifically mentioned in the guide you are following (*"You might encounter the following error"*) although their proposed solution makes no sense to me (they appear to instantiate a python3 virtual env but then persist in trying to use `pip2` instead of `pip3`)

Comment: It worked. Tool was developed in 2015-16. Thank's a lot. God bless you.

Answer (score 1):

Commands to install web3 and Oyente using pip2:

(envsp) ****@lc2530hz:~$ pip2 install web3==3.6.0

(envsp) ****@lc2530hz:~$ pip2 install oyente

Solution derived from Github link:
[oyente issue closed](https://github.com/melonproject/oyente/issues/301)

Oyente working on Ubuntu 18.04:

Successfully installed oyente-0.2.7 z3-solver-4.8.7.0

(envsp) ****@lc2530hz:~$ oyente

usage: oyente [-h] (-s SOURCE | -ru REMOTE_URL) [--version] [-b] [-j] [-e]
              [-p] [--error] [-t TIMEOUT] [-v] [-r] [-gb] [-dl DEPTH_LIMIT]
              [-gl GAS_LIMIT] [-st] [-ll LOOP_LIMIT] [-w]
              [-glt GLOBAL_TIMEOUT] [-a] [--debug] [--generate-test-cases]
oyente: error: one of the arguments -s/--source -ru/--remoteURL is required